# How to fetch record from db by ID?

Tags: java, jdbc

I got this code, but I think this is bad approach, what if there are like 100k results, it will return 100k new People? Are there any other methods that I could use for e.g `ResultSetExtractor` but Im not quite sure how to implement that. Also, should I use `try catch` block?

```java
   public Optional<Person> getPerson(int id) {
        String sql = "SELECT id, name FROM people WHERE id = ?";
        List<Person> people = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, (result, index) -> {
            return new Person(
                    result.getInt("id"),
                    result.getString("name")
            );
        }, id);

        return people.stream().findFirst();
    }
```

Comment: It will not return 100k people you have `WHERE id = ?` it will return just 1 with that ID id should be unique for every single person

Comment: remove `spring-boot` tag and there is no special technic to get 100k record fastest. if you wanna search data fastest than you can use `binary-search`

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej, I am not looking to get 100k records, my question is, is my code optimal for fetching an user by ID with the GET request, I've gotten feedback that my code is bad and I should use `ResultSetExtractor` instead of row mapper. I am looking to hear what people think here

Comment: I think `RowMapper` is best solution for extract data in `spring jdbc`

Answer (score 0):

in a correct design the id field should be unique for every person so this code should only find 1 person as a result.
If the id field is not unique then it is not a good design but the code you wrote would be correct. You dont need try - catch because you a are using a list to store the results so even if theres more than 1 result it wont produce an exception. But that also doesnt make sense because in the end the method is only returning 1 person (people.stream.findFirst()).

Comment: a person told me that this is terrible approach which I did and that I should use `ResultSetExtractor`

Comment: Some code files can be added

Answer (score 0):

If you change the query from

```java
"SELECT id, name FROM people WHERE id = ?"
```

to

```java
"SELECT id, name FROM people WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1"
```

it will only return the first person with a matching `id`.

However, `id` should ideally be unique for each person and the original query will return atmost one result in that case.